# Prepared Statements: Duplicate Key Update with Where

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have these tables:**

```
stundenplan
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+---------+------+
| id | user_id | tag   | stunde | fach    | lehrer  | raum |
+----+---------+-------+--------+---------+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 |     1 |      1 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  2 |       1 |     1 |      2 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  3 |       1 |     1 |      3 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  4 |       1 |     1 |      4 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  5 |       1 |     1 |      5 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  6 |       1 |     1 |      6 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  7 |       1 |     2 |      1 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
|  8 |       1 |     2 |      2 | MATH    | SM      | 101  |
| .. |     ... |   ... |    ... |     ... |     ... |  ... |

users
+---------+----------+----
| user_id | username | ...
+---------+----------+----
|       1 | User1    | ...
+---------+----------+----
```

**My query (which doesn't make sense to me because the user_id is missing in the update part):**

```
$sql = $db->prepare("
INSERT INTO stundenplan
    (tag, stunde, user_id, fach, lehrer, raum )
VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    fach = VALUES(fach),
    lehrer = VALUES(lehrer),
    raum = VALUES(raum)
");
$sql->bind_param('iiissi', $input_tag, $input_stunde, $input_fach, $input_lehrer, $input_raum);
```

If I would have to insert something the query would be this:

```
INSERT INTO stundenplan (tag, stunde, user_id, fach, lehrer, raum) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

If I would have to update the query would be this:

```
UPDATE stundenplan SET fach = ?, lehrer = ?, raum = ? WHERE user_id = ?
```

How can I combine those two queries into one like I've tried before?

Comment: What is the unique key of stundenplan table?

Comment: currently tag, stunde. is tag, stunde, user_id better?

Comment: Is user_id a student? Or is it a technical thing (user who created/modified the plan)?

Comment: One more question - why the key is on `tag, stunde` and you want to have update only on user_id? If we have only one `user_id` in entire table, it would mean that we have to update all rows in the table because of one duplicate.

Comment: I now have a unique key on `tag, stunde, user_id` because this combination of tag, stunde and user_id should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it only on SQL part (your query is correct, but I extended key by `user_id`):

```
    INSERT INTO stundenplan
       (tag, stunde, user_id, fach, lehrer, raum )
    VALUES
       (1,1,1,'MATH_NEW','SM',101)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       fach = VALUES(fach),
       lehrer = VALUES(lehrer),
       raum = VALUES(raum);
```

Please check the demo below. It uses `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` on schema building part and static values on insert (duplicate on `1,1,1` values). After executing `select` statement you can see that values are correctly updated.

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6acc5/1)

The problem is that you cannot modify `UPDATE` conditions in this query (they are exactly the same as from detected duplicate). So there are few possible solutions, all contain 2 queries and transaction:

- Delete duplicate rows from `stundenplan` and insert them again
- Insert not duplicated rows, then update duplicates.

I also found a decent article about fancy inserts/updates [HERE](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/)